# Have tmux not ask for sudo password for a process in session (authenticate beforehand)?

Tags: sudo, tmux

I have already seen [[SOLVED] Why sudo asks for user password in tmux/ssh session? · GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/ciastek/d496ac00ad68f5367db7), and it looks like this is there by design, but I thought I'd ask anyways:

Say I use a command like this:

```
tmux new-session -d 'sudo udevadm monitor -e' \; attach
```

As soon as `tmux` starts the new session, it asks for the `sudo` password, as expected. But then I try to "cheat" by attempting to validate `sudo` beforehand:

```
$ sudo --validate
[sudo] password for user:
$ tmux new-session -d 'sudo udevadm monitor -e' \; attach
```

... and this asks *again* for a `sudo` password as soon as `tmux` starts the session - even if I already entered the password successfully beforehand.

So is there a way to start a `tmux` session with (a) sudo'ed process(es) inside, with only one sudo password validation beforehand?

Comment: Do you have control or influence over your sudoers configuration?

Comment: Thanks, @JeffSchaller - in this case I do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest solution, if you can modify /etc/sudoers, is to unset the `tty_tickets` option for your user:

```
Defaults:yourlogin !tty_tickets
```

Then you can run a sudo command before running tmux, and sudo will update your (single) timestamp and allow the subsequent sudo commands without a password prompt (within the timestamp_timeout).

This is the pertinent option because, typically, the tty_tickets option is set, which requires a password for each tty and tmux starts a new tty.